# Partition bijections

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

How do I prove bijectively that the number of partitions of $n$ with largest part $k$ equals the number of partitions of n with exactly $k$ parts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combinatorics problem based on Ferrers graph](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211836/combinatorics-problem-based-on-ferrers-graph)

Comment: There's a slight difference in these problems, in that here the question asks about partitions with largest part k, and there the question asks about partitions with parts at most size k.

Answer (score 4):

Ferrers diagrams.

Write the partition $n=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_r+k$ as a row of $k$ dots, below it a row of $a_r$ dots, and so on, down to a row of $a_1$ dots, all left-justified. Then the columns give a partition of $n$ into exactly $k$ parts.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a random partition of a number n into 5 distinct parts:

```
24 = 10+6+3+2+1

|*|* * * * * * * * *
|*|* * * * *
|*|* *
|*|*
|*|
```

the bar piece will always be in such a partition: it shows that such partitions are in correspondence with partitions of n whose largest part is 5:

```
* * * * *
* * * *
* * *
* *
* *
*
*
*
*
```